# MVC3 dropdownlistfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I would like to make a dropdown list, with the numbers 0-10. So users can rate something.
At the moment, I have a label: @Html.LabelFor(model=> model.RATE)
How can I modify this code that I will have a dropdown box? And that the value of the dropdown box will be stored in model.RATE?

The label is working, but it would be much better to have a dropdown menu.

**SOLUTION:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RATE, Enumerable.Range(0,11).Select( x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() }));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a list of `SelectListItem` objects that contain the ratings, and then use `Html.DropDownListFor` with the rating stored in your model (`Model.RATE`).

```
@{
    var ratings = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for( var i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ) {
        days.Add( new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString(), Selected = Model.RATE == i } );
    }
}
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.RATE, ratings )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RATE, new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(0, 11)))
```

This will do the data binding to the form and from the form

Comment: 0-10 has 11 elements. So Enumerable.Range(0,11).

Comment: This doesn't work for me...you can't assign an `Enumerable<int>` to an `Enumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: You could use `Enumerable.Range(0,11).Select( x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() } )`

Comment: thats true, but SelectList has a constructor for just an Enumerable, so you can just use the constructor to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks,
This is working for me:

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RATE, Enumerable.Range(0,11).Select( x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString() }));

Comment: how do you add values to the options?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RATE, Model.RateSelectList, "<- Select Option ->")
```

Model.RateSelectList would be of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, m.RATE would be your nullable integer(int?) property. The third parameter would be your default text that would show if m.RATE is null.

Comment: I had no idea how to set a default value until I ran across this. Thanks.