# Asp.net MVC how to populate dropdown list with numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I have seen similar examples where people need to populate with a list of object but all I would like to achieve is to have the numbers 1-10 in my DropdownlistFor in my view. Is there a simple way of doing this. Following is what I have.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfTickets, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberOfTickets)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfTickets)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your model ?

Comment: This is close to what you asked.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709588/mvc3-dropdownlistfor

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumberOfTickets, Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString() }))
```

All this does is create an enumerable of integers between 1 and 10 and then uses a bit of LINQ to transform it into an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that `Html.DropDownListFor` can accept.

Answer (score 4):

Years list from current year to n years back.

```
int startYear = 1980
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DateofEstablishment, Enumerable.Range(0, (DateTime.Now.Year - startYear -1)).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = (DateTime.Now.Year - i).ToString(), Value = i.ToString() }), "Please select year", new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of ASP Mvc or Asp Core you can use something like:

```
<input type="number" asp-for="NumberOfTickets" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Tickets"  min="1" max="10" />
```

Complete code would be:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfTickets, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="number" asp-for="NumberOfTickets" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Tickets"  min="1" max="10" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfTickets)
</div>
```

This is what I use to bind an int value to the model. DropDownListFor expects a IEnumerable<SelectListItem> which you don't need for a simple number dropdown.